# i want to concat 2 field with format space

Tags: mysql

i want field pjPROJECTCODE with 20 character (include character in field too and else is space) and '::' pjDESCRIPTION . my code below

```
SELECT pjPROJECTCODE,CONCAT(pjPROJECTCODE,'::',pjDESCRIPTION) as full 
FROM su_project
```

Comment: what happens if you execute the query? did you get any error? if so please try to post it here.

Comment: And what's your problem? I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: here is what i got "2121::32131" and i want to like this
"2121                ::32131"

Comment: oh space not show in thid :).
i want have space after "2121" 16 space more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Contact with separator allows you to specific how to concat the strings

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CONCAT_WS('::', pjPROJECTCODE, pjDESCRIPTION)
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pjPROJECTCODE,CONCAT(RPAD(pjPROJECTCODE,20,' '),'::',pjDESCRIPTION) as full 
FROM su_project
```

Use RPAD.